# guzzle getbody function accessing the diffrenet elements of response

Tags: php, laravel

i am using guzzle to post some data to some api and recive some data back here is my code :

```
  $response = $client->request('POST', 'http://url/api/v1/transaction/Verify', [
        'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'application/json'],
        'body' => '{
        "tn":"1905463527",
        }'
    ]);
        $responebody = $response->getBody();
```

i exacly dont know if i am getting string or object when ever i use getbody of guzzle but here is what i get when i echo the response :

```
{"errorCode":null,"errorMessage":"Canceled by user.","succeed":false,"tn":1905463527,"verifyCount":35,"amount":10000}
```

now here for example i want to access the "succeed " element and i want to know how can i access to check if it is true or not ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the `Content-Type` header and if it's `application/json` you can run `json_decode` on the body. Take this as an example

```
if ($response->getContentType() == 'application/json') {
    $responseBody = json_decode($response->getContent());
    // now you can access $responseBody->succeed
    ...
}
```